# Extjs 4 mvc: Reference error

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, extjs, extjs4

I get the following error in my view when i try to get a value from the URL to set if the button is disabled.

```
ReferenceError: getUrlParams is not defined
```

Why am i getting this error when the method is defined?

**My View**

```
Ext.define('AM.view.commission.CommissionList' ,{
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.commissionlist',

    store: 'ActiveCommissions',

    initComponent: function() {

        this.columns = [
            {header: 'From', dataIndex: 'from', flex: 2},
            {header: 'To',  dataIndex: 'to',  flex: 2},
            {header: 'Status',  dataIndex: 'status',  flex: 5},
            {header: 'Levels',  dataIndex: 'levels',  flex: 5},
            {header: 'Payment Period',  dataIndex: 'paymentPeriod',  flex:5 }
        ];
        this.buttons = [ {
            id:'addCommissionBtn',
            text : 'Add commission',
            action: 'createcommission',
            disabled: getUrlParams
        }];

        this.callParent(arguments);

    }
    ,getUrlParams: function() {
          var params = Ext.urlDecode(window.location.search.substring(1));
          return params['edit'] || null;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your missing `this`, change it to:

```
disabled: this.getUrlParams()
```

**Edit:**

in your `getUrlParams` method you'll want to return a `Boolean` value like this:

```
return params.edit === 'true';
```

Comment: ah yes, was driving me crazy... with this i am returning either 'true' or 'false' but it keeps setting disabled to be 'false' even if this should be 'true', must i cast the return to be Boolean to take effect?

Comment: If `params['edit']` is a string it will be `true` and `disabled`.

Comment: yes it is and i done a `console.log(params['edit']);` just before returning and it is being returned as `true` or `false` but the button is still disabled... would you know why this is?

Comment: But your passing a `true` value to the disabled property, what are you expecting?

Comment: Sorry I meant regardless if i return `true` or `false` the button is disabled

Comment: The string `'false'` is a truly value.

Comment: is there a way so to convert this to a Boolean so that if i return the string `false` it will be a Boolean value of `false`?